# Auto-align of curly braces in C++ code in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, curly-braces

How do I teach Visual Studio 2010 to format

```
 if(f) {

 }
```

as

```
if(f) 
{

}
```

?

Note 1: I found some solutions for C# (namely to go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->Whatever language->Formatting->New Lines). However, I can't find the option there for C++ code because I don't even see ...->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->New Lines.

Note 2: VS2010 currently doesn't change the latter alignment to the former either if I format the source.

Comment: Many people just find a different text editor that has those features.

Comment: Yeah, I was probably quite naive thinking that such an expensive IDE would already include such a rather simple feature...

Comment: Ive found that I use different editors for different languages or other features.  Edit+ has vertical copy/paste/cut operations, but I like JEdit for other reasons.  Sometimes the built in editor is OK, other times its not LOL

Comment: Parsing C++ is a very hard problem.  Not in the least because existing C++ parser implementations, like the Edison Design Group's parser used in VS2010, never see the actual source code.  A big reason that C# doesn't have a pre-processor.  The leading add-in for C++ is Visual Assist.  I don't think it has this feature either.

Comment: @mort if you want to convert it onetime, have a look into http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_default_bracket_style . After working through the code once, simply punish everyone still using egyptian brackets

Comment: @Najzero: thx for the hint. I'm a part time intern, so I won't be able to punish anyone much ;)

Comment: @mort when you leave and they did not obay `#define true (rand() 0.1 true false) // happy debugging losers` somewhere.

Comment: @Najzero: haha^^ Well, I'm sort of a long-term on and off intern while I'm still studying (which suits me quite well, tbh) and confident that I'll get a permanent position when I got my degree :)

Comment: I recomend: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329